# How to make collision work with userData in Tiled? (LigGDX)

Tags: arrays, libgdx, tiled

currently i'm trying to figure out how to make collision detection work with libgdx and tiled. I collect all bodies from tiled inside an Array

this is the code where i take the bodies from tiled and store them inside an array:

```java
 public static Array<Body> parseTiledObjectLayer(World world, MapObjects mapObjects, int layerValue) {

        switch (layerValue) {


            case 0:

                Array<Body> groundBodies = new Array<Body>();

                for (MapObject mapObject : mapObjects) {
                    Shape shape;


                    if (mapObject instanceof PolylineMapObject) {
                        shape = createPolyline((PolylineMapObject) mapObject);

                    } else if (mapObject instanceof RectangleMapObject) {
                        shape = createRectangle((RectangleMapObject) mapObject);

                    } else if (mapObject instanceof PolygonMapObject) {
                        shape = createPolygon((PolygonMapObject) mapObject);

                    } else {
                        continue;
                    }

                    Body body;
                    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
                    bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
                    body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
                    body.createFixture(shape, 0);

                    groundBodies.add(body);
                    shape.dispose();


                }

                return groundBodies;


            case 1:
                Array<Body> objectBodies = new Array<Body>();

                for (MapObject mapObject : mapObjects) {
                    Shape shape;


                    if (mapObject instanceof PolylineMapObject) {
                        shape = createPolyline((PolylineMapObject) mapObject);

                    } else if (mapObject instanceof RectangleMapObject) {
                        shape = createRectangle((RectangleMapObject) mapObject);

                    } else if (mapObject instanceof PolygonMapObject) {
                        shape = createPolygon((PolygonMapObject) mapObject);

                    } else {
                        continue;
                    }

                    Body body;
                    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
                    bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
                    body = world.createBody(bodyDef);

                    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
                    fixtureDef.shape = shape;
                    body.createFixture(shape, 0);

                    objectBodies.add(body);
                    shape.dispose();


                }

                return objectBodies;

            default: //if default returns null we don't have to return null outside the switch loop and if we return something
                //inside a switch statement we don't use the statement break;

                return null;
        }


}
```

Now in another class i return the static array to collect the information from it and in this other class i also implement ContactListener.

In this variable i retrieve the above static array:

```java
private Array<Body> objectBodies = MapLoader.parseTiledObjectLayer(world, map.getLayers().get(1).getObjects(), 1);
objectBodies.get(1).setUserData("Object");
```

and here i also try to assign a UserData for collision.

Now here i actually try to check if there is collision:

```java
@Override
public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
    Fixture body1;
    Fixture body2;

    if(contact.getFixtureA().getUserData() == "Player"){
        body1 = contact.getFixtureA();
        body2 = contact.getFixtureB();
    } else {
        body1 = contact.getFixtureB();
        body2 = contact.getFixtureA();
    }

    if(body1.getUserData() == "Player" && body2.getUserData() == "Object"){
        System.out.println("collided");
    }
}
```

Everything seems fine but for some reason when Player and Object collide nothing seems to be happening. I don't have this error when setting the userdata inside the static method. Any help appriciated.

Comment: Figured it out, yust the same way you make a Array<Body> you also need to create an Array<Fixture> to assign a userdata. For some reason body.setUserData doesn't work for me atleast not.

Comment: So why not answer your own question? :-)

Comment: Yeah just in case someone else was having this problem maybe it would have been some use to them. (in the future)